# Python, Tkinter,How to change GUI based on buttonclick

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter in a programming assignment and have the following problem.
I want the user to enter the value in a textbox, and I want to add additional fields on the GUI based on the number entered in the textbox when he/she clicks the submit-button.

I tried to place code inside of the function 'displayText()', which is called when the submit-button is pressed; however, the GUI-related code that I placed inside of it was loaded when the window was loaded.

```
import tkinter

#When user clicks on button
def displayText():
    #DO CHANGE IN GUI

root = tkinter.Tk()
button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Submit", command=displayText())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Submit", command=displayText())
```

The `command` option takes a *reference* to a command. What you are doing instead is *calling* a command (`displayText()`) and giving the results of that command to the option. You need to remove the `()` so that the actual command to run is associated with the option, like so:

```
button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Submit", command=displayText)
```